# What is the meaning of でも 私 あなたのそういうところ すきよ?

Tags: meaning, particles

I was reading a manga and the character said:

> でも 私 あなたのそういうところ すきよ

I translated it as "You like someone such as me." I may be completely wrong because ところ throws me off. I know some particles are being omitted, but I just don't know which ones.

Answer (score 8):

> でも 私 あなたのそういうところ すきよ

You can interpret it as:

> でも 私**は** あなたのそういうところ**が(orは)** すきよ

Literally, "But I like that part of you."

<sub>「あなたのそういうところ**が**好き」 means "I like that part of you" "That's what I like about you" (implying "That's the main factor I like about you"), while 「あなたのそういうところ**は**好き」 sounds more like "That part of you, I like it" "That part of you is favorable to me" (this may imply "That's not the main factor" or "That part I like, but some other part I don't like"). The example in question sounds closer to the latter.</sub>

---

The ところ is "part (of you)". It can refer to one's personality, character, or the way one behaves. Examples:

> 「あなたの優しいところ」
>   *lit.* "kind part of you" → "your kind personality"
>   「彼女のどんなところが好きですか。」
>   *lit.* "Which part of her do you like?" → "What do you like about her?"